# React Apollo graphql HOC loading is false but no data field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm trying to store data in apollo cache and get this data in my component by graphql HOC

Here I init Apollo Client and add user data to the apollo cache:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  resolvers: {}
});
cache.writeQuery({
  query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
  data: {
    userData: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Alexander",
      email: "email@domain.com"
    }
  }
});

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Main />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

Here is my GET_CURRENT_USER query:

```
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

export const GET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
  query getUserData($id: ID!) {
    userData @client {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`;
```

Here I wrapp my component into graphql HOC:

```
...
export default graphql(GET_CURRENT_USER)(ProfileScreen);
```

And I'm checking props.data property into render method of ProfileScreen component, it's fired 2 times:

> 1. error: undefined; 
>      loading: true; 
>      no userData field
> 2. error: undefined; 
>      loading: false;
>      no userData field

Also I checked Apollo Cache and userData field is stored

Environment:

1. "apollo-boost": "^0.4.3",
2. "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
3. "react-native": "0.60.4",
4. "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.2",
5. "react": "16.8.6"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding __typename field to the userData object